# How to merge two images for retina display (@2x)?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, retina-display

I want to add an `UIImage` in the `UIImageView` of the `UITableViewCell` inside the `UITableViewController`. This works fine:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

But now, I want to merge two images and use the code [I've found here](http://transoceanic.blogspot.com/2011/09/objective-c-merge-two-images.html):

```
UIImage *mergedImage = [MyUtils mergeImage:@"myBackImage.png" withImage:@"myFrontImage.png"];
```

This works very good with an old iPhone (320x480) but not on retina display. In my project, there are "@2x"-versions of every image. I analyze the code and have an explanation for the problem.

a) on iPhone 3 without merging (WORKS)
- image width: 28.0
- image height: 29.0
- image scale: 1.0

b) on iPhone 3 with merging (WORKS)
- image width: 28.0
- image height: 29.0
- image scale: 1.0

c) on iPhone 4 without merging (WORKS)
- image width: 28.0
- image height: 29.0
- image scale: 2.0

d) on iPhone 4 with merging (WORKS NOT)
- image width: 56.0
- image height: 58.0
- image scale: 1.0

As you can see, the merging converts the "28.0/29.0/2.0" to an "56.0/58.0/1.0" image. And this images gets displayed to big on retina display.

**How can I correctly merge two images to get an image with a scale of 2.0?**

---

#### Appendix: the code I'm using for merging two images [(from here)](http://transoceanic.blogspot.com/2011/09/objective-c-merge-two-images.html)

```
+ (UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)first withImage:(UIImage*)second
{
 // get size of the first image
 CGImageRef firstImageRef = first.CGImage;
 CGFloat firstWidth = CGImageGetWidth(firstImageRef);
 CGFloat firstHeight = CGImageGetHeight(firstImageRef);

 // get size of the second image
 CGImageRef secondImageRef = second.CGImage;
 CGFloat secondWidth = CGImageGetWidth(secondImageRef);
 CGFloat secondHeight = CGImageGetHeight(secondImageRef);

 // build merged size
 CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstWidth, secondWidth), MAX(firstHeight, secondHeight));

 // capture image context ref
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mergedSize);

 //Draw images onto the context
 [first drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstWidth, firstHeight)];
 [second drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, secondWidth, secondHeight)];

 // assign context to new UIImage
 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 // end context
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compute the merged size based on the `UIImage` sizes, not the `CGImage` sizes, and you need to create the graphics context using the largest of the image's scales.  Try this:

```
CGSize firstSize = first.size;
CGSize secondSize = second.size;
CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstSize.width, secondSize.width),
    MAX(firstSize.height, secondSize.height));
CGFloat mergedScale = MAX(first.scale, second.scale);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mergedSize, NO, mergedScale);

[first drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
[second drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

Comment: @rob mayoff hey, see you again, this works for me as well, thanks!